# What's the proper way to mutate a prop from a directive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

`my-component` has an `error` property. I want to mutate that property from my directive specifically for when the binding isn't present.

```
<my-component
    v-bind:error="things.error"
    v-my-custom-directive>
</my-component>

<my-component
    v-my-custom-directive>
</my-component>
```

So I have my directive:

```
Vue.directive('my-custom-directive', {
    bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
        const stuff = '' //work
        vnode.componentInstance.$props.error = stuff;        
    }
}
```

This results in the following error:

`Avoid mutating a prop directly`

Comment: I am not sure that it is possible to do what you want with no more than just the directive.  Note that message your are receiving is not an "error" it is only a warning.  So you can ignore it and when in production mode it wont show.  It is not the best solution but once in a similar situation I ended up just ignoring the warning because in my case as well as yours I had no concern of the prop being over-written by the parent.

Comment: @skribe The warning is there for a reason: prop should not be mutated because it technically "belongs" to the parent, and the parent is always the singular source of truth in VueJS. What you want is to actually copy the prop to a data object, and you can modify the data object in any way you want.

Comment: @Terry  I completely agree and think there may be a better way perhaps as I suggest in my answer below.  In a sense here in the OPs example there is no real parent since the directive is essentially part of the component, no? There are rare instances however where you don't have control of the situation, which once happened where when using someone elses component that I could not modify, I broke the rule without any immediate consequences.  That does not mean there will not be future consequences though. :)

Comment: @skribe Yup, I read your answer and it looks great! Also doesn't break encapsulation in contrast with fiddling with the data object (then the directive needs to know what key to modify).

Comment: @Terry  Thanks!  It seems like there should be a way to simplify this further, but I can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't discern all the specifics of your purpose, but would it work for your purpose to dispense with the prop, and rather use a `$on` event listener in your component, and $emit the event from your directive?

In your component:

```
data(){
  return{
    error: null
 }
},
created(){
  this.$on('error', function(error){
    this.error = error;
 });
}
```

In your directive:

```
Vue.directive('my-custom-directive', {
   bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
       const stuff = 'Has error' //work
       vnode.componentInstance.$emit('error', stuff);        
   }
})
```

Check out my jfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/mL18fb2x/